# How can I fetch gmail or outlook mails from my android application using java mail but without providing any password for that account

Tags: android, outlook, smtp, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

Till now my search failed for SMTP, pop3 and Imap as all of them require a password. Also what I understood is that the password is a property of mail server so their is nothing much a client can do but is there any way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is to be expected - don't' you think it would be a huge security hole if I could read your emails without knowing your password?

Comment: Totally agree, so what are the alternatives to typing passwords, is there any consent screen facility ..

Comment: Do you mean like OAuth? There is nothing like that in the POP3, SMTP, or IMAP4 protocols (all of which are over 30 years old).